# How to break text from recordForm after resize of screen

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css, component

When I change the size of my screen the text isn't breaking. It continue past the screen and exceeds the container.

Here my component :

```
     <div class="slds-page-header ">
        <div class="slds-page-header__col-actions">
            <div class="slds-page-header__controls">
                <div class="slds-page-header__control">
                    <lightning:recordForm
                    recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                    objectApiName="Account"
                    fields="{!v.fields}"
                    columns="{!v.fieldsSize}"
                    density="comfy"
                    mode="readonly" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My CSS :

```
.THIS {
    background-color: white;
}

.THIS .slds-border_bottom, .THIS .slds-border--bottom {
    border: none;
}

.THIS {
    
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -1rem;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.THIS .slds-page-header__control {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.THIS .slds-has-flexi-truncate{
    width:210px;
}
```

I tried using `display: flex` and `word-wrap: break-word` to go in line when my screen size change but it doesn't workd. I don't know if I need to change my CSS to allow this or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a width for your element. Without any width the browser won't know how/when to wrap the text.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly fine with 100% !